# Find for each sub array in multidimensional array, if element on fixed position is highest value for this sub array

Tags: php, arrays, max, sub-array

Hello all.

For each sub array in $arr_rgb (Fig.01) I have to find:
If element with $key number 1 is the highest number in this sub array, then return the $key number 
of the sub array (Fig.03 and Fig.04.
So far, I can find highest number for each sub array – fig.02

In the attached image the "trouble" I have is explained.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QMy3.png]

And the code that I use so far:

```
<?php
$hex_splited = [
        ['00','00','00'], 
        ['10', '11', '10'], 
        ['F0', '1A', 'C3'],
        ['0F', 'FE', 'F4'],
       ];

$arr_rgb = [];
$count2 = count($hex_splited);

for ($i=0; $i < $count2; $i++) { 
    
    $inn_count = count($hex_splited[$i]);
    
    for ($j=0; $j < $inn_count; $j++) { 
            
        $val = hexdec($hex_splited[$i][$j]);
        $arr_rgb[$i][$j] = $val;

        foreach ($arr_rgb as $key => $value) {
            $resultMax[$key] = max($value);
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($resultMax);
echo "</pre>";

    echo "<table border='1'>";
for ($m=0; $m < $count2; $m++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($k=0; $k < $inn_count; $k++) { 
        echo "<td>";
        echo $arr_rgb[$m][$k];
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Would you be done by storing the (row, column) pair of the max value you find in the first nested loop, and return/display that pair if it has a column value of 1?

Comment: Why would the output be just `1, 3` – what about the first sub-array? The value `00` at position 1 _is_ identical to the max of all values there as well.

Comment: the exact output is as is on the picture, but if you have suggestions may be they can help me too.

Comment: if all elements are equal, then return nothing

Comment: _“the exact output is as is on the picture”_ - you need to explain the _logic_ behind stuff like this, not just go “as in the picture”. Otherwise, I am going to give you `function foo() { return [1, 3]; }` and say, that fulfills your requirement :-P

Comment: lol you are right, sorry:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determining the maximum using `max` only properly works for integers, so I would use `array_map` with `hexdec` to achieve that.

Then all it needs is a comparison of the value at position 1 with that maximum, and if they are the same, then the index gets added to the result array:

```
$result = [];
foreach($hex_splited as $key => $value) {
  if(hexdec($value[1]) == max(array_map('hexdec', $value))) {
    $result[] = $key;
  }
}
var_dump($result);
```

This gets you `0, 1, 3` as result. (As IMHO it should be, according to your stated requirements - the value `00` at position 1 in the first sub-array *is* also the maximum of all values in that sub-array. If you need to exclude 0 values, then you’ll have to modify accordingly.)

EDIT:

> if all elements are equal, then return nothing

Okay, that can also be implemented quite easily - we use `array_count_values`, and if the count of *that* is only 1, then that means all the elements had the exact same value.

So then it becomes

```
foreach($hex_splited as $key => $value) {
  if(count(array_count_values($value)) != 1 &&
      hexdec($value[1]) == max(array_map('hexdec', $value))) {
    $result[] = $key;
  }
}
```

With that, you get `[1, 3]` as $result here.

Comment: Very nicely done :) Thank you very much. Appreciate it .

Comment: With this code only when all 3 values are equal we do not get result back, but if 2 of them are equal it returns the key of the array(3) = [ 220, 220, 4]; result [3]. Any idea :)

Comment: If only two out of the three items are equal, then `array_count_values` will return an array with two entries - so make that part `count(array_count_values($value)) < 3` then. Does that do what you want now?

Comment: Like this works perfect:
`if(count(array_count_values($value)) < 3 && hexdec($value[1]) == max(array_map('hexdec', $value))) {

$resultNone[] = $key;

} elseif (count(array_count_values($value)) != 1 && hexdec($value[1]) == max(array_map('hexdec', $value))) {
       
$resultMax[] = $key;
      }`